# Effect on lua scripts when redis is unable to save in background due to memory allocation issues

Tags: django, lua, redis

I recently added some Lua scripts to a Django application (for interfacing with a Redis backend). In production (although not in development), the set up ends up giving me the following error:

```
Error running script (call to f_8c07b227bc796743f66bad8dbe75a5bf8fcc8cd6): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: -MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.
```

While this happens, if I look at redis logs, I'm seeing `can't save in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory`.

I get what's happening. My question is, howcome redis remains functional when memory can't be allocated for background saving, but lua scripts crash? Is there a way to avoid such a scenario?

---

FYI, following is how my `lua_scripts.py` module is laid out:

```
import redis
from location import REDLOC2 #location of relevant unix socket

my_server = redis.StrictRedis(unix_socket_path=REDLOC2)

# Get recent
lualatestlogins = """
local l = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]-600, '+inf') -- returns key:value pairs
local c = {}
for _, v in pairs(l) do
  local p = v:find(':')
  local i = v:sub(1,p-1)
  c[#c+1] = i
end
return c"""
getlatestlogins = my_server.register_script(lualatestlogins)

# Evict old
luacleanselogins = """
redis.call('ZREMRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], '-inf', '(' .. ARGV[1]-600)"""
cleanselogins = my_server.register_script(luacleanselogins)

# -- Store new
luastorelogin = """
redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2] .. ':' .. ARGV[3])
redis.call('SET',KEYS[2],ARGV[3])
redis.call('EXPIRE',KEYS[2],600)"""
storelogin = my_server.register_script(luastorelogin)

# Retrieve collisions
luaretrieveclones = """
local q = redis.call('GET',KEYS[2]) 
if q == nil or q == '' then
  return nil               
else
  local l = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]-600, '+inf')
  local c = {}
  for _, v in pairs(l) do  
    local p = v:find(':')  
    local i = v:sub(1,p-1) 
    local n = v:sub(p+1)   
    if n == q then         
      c[#c+1] = i          
    end
  end

  return c
end"""
retrieveclones = my_server.register_script(luaretrieveclones)
```

Comment: You say that "Redis remains functional", but is that true of all commands? I'm just guessing here, but the error message ("Commands that may modify the data set are disabled") makes me think that reads will continue to work, but that potential writes (including Lua scripts) will be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message told you everything: **Commands that may modify the data set are disabled.**

Redis tries to fork a new process to do the background saving, but fails because of lack of memory. In this case, Redis disables any update to the database. Otherwise, the data in memory, and data on disk will be inconsistent.

> how come redis remains functional when memory can't be allocated for background saving

Redis can still serve read-only requests, and refuse any requests that may modify the database.

> but lua scripts crash?

You lua scripts tries to modify the database, e.g. `redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2] .. ':' .. ARGV[3])`, and fails.

> Is there a way to avoid such a scenario?

1. You should monitor this kind of error, and move Redis to a new machine with more memory to scale up, or use Redis cluster to scale out.
2. In your lua script, use `redis.pcall` instead of `redis.call`. If `redis.call` fails, the whole script will terminate. However, if `redis.pcall` fails, it traps the error and return a lua table for the error message. You can check the returned table to see if your call runs successfully.

Comment: Cool answer. Thanks!